Conditional recursive query in SQL Server
I have these 2 tables:
TABLE 1



Id
Shortname
ParentId




C1
Child1
P1


P1
Parent1
GP1


GP1
GrandParent1
NULL


C2
Child2
P2


P2
Parent2
GP1



TABLE 2



Id
Setting




GP1
5


C2
1



The logic is the following: if we don't find a value for the setting in table 2, we are going up the hierarchy defined in table 1 until we find something.
In the example:

if I want the setting for item C2 I will retrieve 1 (direct value of C2)

if I want the setting for item C1 I will retrieve 5 (I have nothing in table 2, I'll look to its parent -P1 regarding table 1-, still nothing, I'll look to its parent -GP1-)

if I want the setting for item P2,I will retrieve 5 (Parent is GP1)


I have tried to implement a recursive query but without success for the moment, I need help.
Thanks
So far now, the best I have:
with settings as
(
    select N.Id,N.ParentId, N.ShortName,DTC.Setting 
    from Table1 as N 
    left join Table2 as DTC on DTC.Id=N.id
)
, RecursiveTable AS (
    SELECT no.Id,ShortName,ParentId,Setting 
    FROM settings as no
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n.Id,n.ShortName, n.ParentId,n.Setting 
    FROM settings n

    INNER JOIN RecursiveTable rn ON n.id = rn.ParentId
)
select * from RecursiveTable


what query did you try?

This fiddle might help us collaborate on a solution https://dbfiddle.uk/eCLSpSXh

I can't see any problems in the recursive query that you have tried, I wonder why that would be

@GuidoG i guess the problem is that even if you get the parents etc, it's complicated to get the setting since it can come from various parent levels

@siggemannen I wrote that comment as sarcastic since when I wrote it the query was not visible for us yet

I added some settings to your example, you can do something like this perhaps:
;WITH Table1 AS(
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'C1', N'Child1', N'P1')
    ,   (N'P1', N'Parent1', N'GP1')
    ,   (N'GP1', N'GrandParent1', NULL)
    ,   (N'C2', N'Child2', N'P2')
    ,   (N'P2', N'Parent2', N'GP1')
) t (Id,Shortname,ParentId)
)
, table2 AS (
SELECT  *
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'GP1', 5)
    ,   (N'C2', 1)
    ,   (N'C1', 10)
) t (Id,Setting)
)
, hierarchy AS (
    SELECT  id, shortname, parentid, 1 AS level
    FROM    table1 t
    
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  h.id, h.shortname, t.parentid, h.level + 1
    FROM    hierarchy h
    INNER JOIN table1 t
        ON  t.ID = h.ParentID
    )
, settings AS (
    SELECT  h.ID, h.shortname, setting.ID AS SettingID, setting.Setting
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY h.ID ORDER BY h.level, case when setting.Id = h.id then 0 else 1 end) AS sort
    FROM    hierarchy h
    INNER JOIN table2 setting
        ON  setting.Id IN (h.id, h.parentid)
    )
SELECT  *
FROM    settings s
WHERE   s.sort = 1


I create a hierarchy-CTE of IDs by taking all rows and then going up to their parent and parent's parent ID. A level-column keeps track of where we are in the tree
Then, inside the settings-CTE, we join on the settings "table" by either ID or parentID value, this allows us to fetch all the setting values in the tree.
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY h.ID ORDER BY h.level, case when setting.Id = h.id then 0 else 1 end) creates a ranking for the setting, since we want it from the closest level, we order it by h.level and then by how it matches against the h.Id or not.
Finally, we retrieve all the settings belonging on the lowest level by doing: WHERE   s.sort = 1

Output:



ID
shortname
SettingID
Setting
sort




C1
Child1
C1
10
1


C2
Child2
C2
1
1


GP1
GrandParent1
GP1
5
1


P1
Parent1
GP1
5
1


P2
Parent2
GP1
5
1




I think you had your recursive join backward conceptually as it relates to parent and child. Maybe there's something slightly more elegant but this is in line with the path you were on:
with Base as (
    select t.Id, t.ParentId, t.ShortName, DTC.Setting 
    from Table1 as t left outer join Table2 as DTC on DTC.Id = t.id
), Settings as (
    select Id, ShortName, Setting,
        case when setting is not null then Id end as RootId,
        case when setting is null then ParentId end as ParentId
    from Base
    union all
    select s.Id, s.ShortName, b.Setting,
        case when b.setting is not null then b.Id end,
        case when b.setting is null then b.ParentId end
    from Settings s inner join Base b on b.Id = s.ParentId
)
select Id, ShortName, Setting, RootId from Settings
where Setting is not null;

https://dbfiddle.uk/SIkgyCsO
If generating a list of all the settings at all levels, it might make more sense to walk the tree in the other direction and then just propagate the setting downward. I presume that the typical use for this will be from a known starting point working backward though.

Not recursive but produces the expected results
SELECT Id, Setting, 'From Table 2' as Source
FROM TABLE2   

UNION ALL  

SELECT T1.Id,t2.Setting, 'Direct child via Table 1' as Source
FROM TABLE2 t2
INNER JOIN TABLE1 t1 ON t2.Id=t1.ParentId
WHERE T2.ID <> T1.ID

UNION ALL  

SELECT T1.Id,t2.Setting, 'Grand child via Table 1 2x' as Source
FROM TABLE2 t2
INNER JOIN TABLE1 t3 ON t2.Id=t3.ParentId
INNER JOIN TABLE1 t1 ON t3.Id=t1.ParentId
WHERE  t1.ID not in (Select ID FROM table2)

fiddle



Id
Setting
Source




GP1
5
From Table 2


C2
1
From Table 2


P1
5
Direct child via Table 1


P2
5
Direct child via Table 1


C1
5
Grand child via Table 1 2x




It can't work as we don't know the level of hierarchy, could be 1 as 10. Thanks
